# Setting UserRights in Azure AD MIP SDK doesn't let me add a global "AuthenticatedUsers"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk, microsoft-information-protection

We are using the Azure MIP SDK to encrypt documents.
The API is pretty simple and the samples are good when you use the template functionality.
But... We want to generate the Protection Descriptor ourselves.
Works well with users emails. But in all the doc/samples impossible to find how to define a role or permission for "All Authenticated Users" (The definition exists in the templates).
Any comment/suggestions would be most welcome.

```
var newRights = new List<UserRights>{
                            new UserRights(
                                new List<string> {
                                    "aip@someaddress.com",
                                },
                                new List<string> {"owner"}
                            ),
                        };
ProtectionDescriptor protectionDescriptor = new ProtectionDescriptor(newRights);
```

Comment: can you please let me know if you are able to apply custom protection descriptor without any templates using MIP SDK ? Could you please share some detail ? My requirement is, need to protect PDF using MIP. We don't have any templates configured. Is there anyway we can protect other than labelling?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after serious digging. the email value for any user is "ANYONE" upper case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/msipc/ipc-user

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [MIP SDK](https://aka.ms/mipsdkdocs)?

If so, I'll double check the docs and get this added if we've missed it.

Comment: Yes. MIP SDK.. C#... Adding it to the doc would be nice ...